# I have blown the component shown, what is it?

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I stupidly blew this component by connecting it to 240 V rather than the 12 V I was intending to (it's a DSE855 from Deep Sea).

The top left is -V and the one below it is +V. Is this a diode? If it is, can anyone identify it or guess at the specs?

I would like to at least have a go at replacing it (I really have no specialist equipment apart from the obligatory soldering iron) but willing to give it a go! It's scrap anyway unless I try.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a capacitor. Many more things are likely dead.

Comment: Is the fuse intact? (white+gold, should conduct). Also, it would be helpful if you could post a photo of the other side of the board.

Comment: Thanks, I have just done a continuity test across the fuse and its shows good. I have a pic of the other side, but not sure how to add now. Pic now added.

Comment: Well does it work if you give it 12V? Or remove the charred component? It was likely a protection component for overvoltage or reverse polarity. Chanses are that many other components are damaged instead of that one you see.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. A small thing but please avoid using 'pic' for picture or photo, as your title originally had. A PIC is a type of very popular microcontroller, so people can be misled by the term, particularly the way it was in your title. Thanks :-)

Comment: Could have been a protection varistor, remove it and test the board.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be a SMD varistor for transient voltage protection. They do come in these "resistor-like" packages with black body.

A resistor doesn't make much sense to me. Sometimes you might have some high resistance bleeding resistor between + and - to get rid of residual voltages after removing the supply. But directly behind the connector would be an odd place for such a resistor.

I don't think it's a capacitor either, as black is not a very common body color.

Also don't believe it's a diode. That's not a common package for diodes and there doesn't seem to be any cathode marking (a diode in such a place would be mounted in reverse direction, i. e. the cathode facing the positive supply).

Comment: Could also be a TVS diode in SMB package (DO-214AA). But I agree, that it looks more like SMD varistor.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet mentions "cranking dropouts", suggesting an automotive environment.

Most likely the component is a multilayer, SMT chip type MOV, used to absorb transients such as relay switching.  Likely it does not offer load dump protection (100ms-long excursion to 50V or more, due to the alternator suddenly becoming unloaded -- a rare event, aftermarket equipment often skips dealing with it).

The next components are a SMT "brick" fuse (white with metal end caps), an MLCC (tan ceramic), and polarity protection diode (I see the ST logo, but can't make out the number, seems like "G511", which doesn't sound like anything?).  I'm guessing the path disappears into the board.

Although, the next large component is MJD32C, a PNP power transistor; it could be used to switch off power if the voltage goes too high.  This is a common strategy to deal with automotive load dump.  It could also be used for voltage [pre]regulation, though an NPN or N-MOSFET is a more likely choice.  It is only rated 100V though, so if the 240V got this far into the circuit, it's likely everything has failed.

On the upside, it does seem to be well designed hardware, at least as far as the input circuit shown here.  Likely it passes ISO 7637-2 at typical 12V levels.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely an SMT resistor or an SMT MLCC, but could also be a ferrite. If it's between two power pins, it's most likely a cap. If you connected 240V to it, anything downstream is also dead. Ohm out the 12V rail and check for shorts. Remove offending components if they are short.